# Is this sum of Binary Numbers an Overflow?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, binary, number-systems

I have a question of the likes of 
21 + 11
I converted each number to binary getting:

### **010101**

### +

### **001011**

I got a result of :
$100000$ which is $32$ in decimal

Thus it is correct that $21+11 = 32$.
However, since the signed bit is a 1, which means its negative, does that mean their is an overflow? I'm really confused on this. Does a Carry out also mean theirs an overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define first what **length your binary strings are**.

For your case: 
If you have binary strings of length 6 then there is no overflow but if your strings are of length 5 then you have overflow because you need one more place to represent your result.

As for the sign bit, then you have to define again in what form the binary strings are given

For example $111$ in **signed** form is equal to $-3$ but in **unsigned** form the same three bits $111$ are equal to $7$

Comment: RIght, sorry the length is 6. I get it now thanks, if it was 5, this would be an overflow.

Comment: Also what about the rule of two positives = Negative making an overflow, and two negatives making a positive = Overflow, does that also follow here?

Comment: if you have sum of two positives how can you get a negative?? Think it like this. Depending on length and form, the results in a given range do not cause overflow $A\leq result \leq B$ So try to find A and B and check if your result is inside! The rule you wrote seems to work, but I am not sure it it always stands true!

Comment: Because this is what it tells me on this page: http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/tc/orules.html

Comment: "If the sum of two positive numbers yields a negative result, the sum has overflowed."

Comment: Yes, it is another way of saying that your result is out of the range of not-overflowed results!